# Is there a way to make a (non-jailbroken) iPhone look battery dead?

Tags: iphone, battery

I am looking for a way to make my iPhone look 'battery dead' with no practical short-term means of bypassing. Is there a way to make it? Even hardware modifications or putting something into the lightning connector (maybe to trigger something that doesn't cause permanent damage) are okay for me (as long as it doesn't involve breaking something permanently).

What I want is that: activate it and for someone doesn't know how to deactivate it, the phone will look dead. And there should (of course) be an easy way to deactivate it and put everything back to normal.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are basically trying to (temporarily) make the iPhone dead? Like, not turn on at all?

Comment: @Hexa yes. It may not be dead at all technically, but it may *appear* dead (like hitting the power button or home button not turning it on or showing out of battery symbol).